# echo the whole post from a PHP page using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a search using Ajax PHP..Anything is going good but when i try to echo the whole post in my search page from PHP script.it doesn't work.Inclucding the PHP script in the page showing all the posts without clicking the specific.
Is there any way to echo using ajax without including the PHP script ?

This is my **search.php**:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#search').keyup(function(){
                    var sea = $('#search').val();
                    $.get('test.php',{getsearch:sea},function(data){
                        $('#result').show().html(data);
                    });
                });

                $('#search').blur(function(){
                    $('#result').hide();
                });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cover">
    <div class="btns-holder">
            <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search for something.." id="search" autocomplete="off" /><input type="submit" name="sub" value="" id="sub" />
    </div>
</div>



<div id="result">
</div>
<?php
$post = @$_GET['p'];
$que = "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `id`='$post'";
$run  = mysqli_query($con,$que);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($con,$que)):

?>
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" widrh="500px" height="450px" style="float: left;"></img>
    <h2 style="font-family: sans-serif;"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</body>
```

This is **test.php** from where i want to echo the data:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "ajax_search";
    $con  = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "connection failed".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$search = @$_GET['getsearch'];
$que = "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$search%'";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$que);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)):
?>

    <a href="search.php?p=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width="50px" height="45px"></img>
            <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3></br>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* isn't much of a technical problem statement. What part does work? Doesn't appear you have used any error handling anywhere...have you looked in browser dev tools console and network?

Comment: I don't understand the specific problem. "*when i try to echo the whole post in my search page from PHP script.it doesn't work.*" Would you please rephrase.